# Nodejs Passport Authentication Error - Cannot call method authenticate for undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I'm trying to authenticate a user when they sign up using Node.js and Passport.js, but whenever I call the authenticate method I get and error saying:

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot call method 'authenticate' of undefined
>    at /Users/MarcellusPowell/Desktop/Stake/Code/routes/routes.js:53:13
>    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/MarcellusPowell/Desktop/Stake/Code/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:76:5)
>    at next (/Users/MarcellusPowell/Desktop/Stake/Code/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:100:13)
>    at next (/Users/MarcellusPowell/Desktop/Stake/Code/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:94:14)
>    at Route.dispatch (/Users/MarcellusPowell/Desktop/Stake/Code/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:81:3)
>    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/MarcellusPowell/Desktop/Stake/Code/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:76:5)
>    at /Users/MarcellusPowell/Desktop/Stake/Code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:227:24
>    at Function.proto.process_params (/Users/MarcellusPowell/Desktop/Stake/Code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:305:12)
>    at /Users/MarcellusPowell/Desktop/Stake/Code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:221:12
>    at Function.match_layer (/Users/MarcellusPowell/Desktop/Stake/Code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:288:3
> ```

This is my **app.js** file:

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var staticFavicon = require('static-favicon');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(cookieParser());
//app.use(express.json());
//app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(methodOverride());
//app.use(staticFavicon(path.join(__dirname + '/public/images/favicon.ico')));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'moneymaking',
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 86400000
  }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/public'));

require('./routes/routes')(app, fs);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

I call the method in my routes.js like this:

```js
var fs = require ('fs');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var passport = require('passport');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
 host  : '',
 user   : '',
 password : '',
 port   : '',
 database : ''
})


module.exports = function(app, fs, passport){
 
 app.route('/')

  .get(function(req, res, next){
   res.redirect("/home");
  })

 app.route('/home')

  .get(function(req, res, next){
   res.render('index', {title: 'home'});
  })


 app.route('/signup')

  .get(function(req, res, next){
   res.render('signup', {title: 'signup', message: req.sessionmessages});

  })

  .post(function(req, res, next){
   
  })

 app.route('/investor')

  .get(function(req, res, next){
   res.render('investor', {title: 'signup', message: req.sessionmessages});
  })

 app.route('/company')

  .get(function(req, res, next){
   res.render('company', {title: 'Comapny signup', message: req.sessionmessages});
  })

  .post(function(req, res, next){
   passport.authenticate('local-signup', function(err, user, info){
    req.session.messages = info.messages;
    console.log(req.session.messages);
    if(err)
     req.session.messages = "Error creating user"
    console.log(req.session.messages);

    return res.redirect('/home')
   })
  })

 app.route('/about')

  .get(function(req, res, next){
   res.render('about', {title: 'About Us', message: req.sessionmessages});
  })

 //app.route('/:var(login)?')

  /*
  .get(funtction(req, res, next){
   if(req.isAuthenticated())
    res.redirect("/home");
   res.render('login', {title: 'Need a Name', message: req.sessionmessages})
  })
  
  .post.(function(req, res, next)){

  });
  */

 
}
```

And I serialize and deserialize the user in my **passport.js** file here:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
})

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
})
```

Comment: Can you post the whole routes file? the `passport` reference is not set there I assume

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin I've edited the post to include the full routes file.  I don't believe the 'passport' reference is the problem though.